# How to get timezone value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, timezone

I have SSRS reports which displays the execution time each time while running the report. 
I would like to display the timezone value next to it . How do i get that.

Thanks,
Jaz

Answer (score 3):

To get the timezone on the server, use:

```
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(Now()).ToString()
```

Comment: My server is in CET time. Is this function is the right one to use then?.

Comment: Are you looking to display the server time zone?  or the time zone of the person running the report?